# Item name not displaying properly in a custom mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to create a new Minecraft mod on 1.12.2 with some basic additions, and all is going smoothly, except that custom items aren't displaying names properly. I am trying to get a ruby item into the game, but the creative menu displays it as item.Ruby.name instead.

My error is virtually the same as the one here:
[Block textures and block names not loading minecraft forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770905/block-textures-and-block-names-not-loading-minecraft-forge), I followed their advice and got a lang file, but it still does not show properly. I have tried naming the file en_US.lang and en_us.lang, I have tried capital and lowercase names for item and name.

Inside my lang file is:

```java
item.Ruby.name = Ruby
```

which should be correct.

I have a .json file, envm is my mod id:

```java
{
   "parent": "item/generated",
   "textures": {
       "layer0": "envm:items/ruby"
   }
}
```

I am following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQLhheYcnrY and all of my code and layout is the same as his, besides my mod id and username. Just put a comment if you want me to share more code, I don't nkow how much I need to put here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No spaces in lang file

<sup>At least, around the `=`</sup>

```
item.Ruby.name = Ruby
```

should be

```
item.Ruby.name=Ruby
```

When you use `item.Ruby.name = Ruby`, the game is trying to replace `item.Ruby.name_` (where `_` is the space) and that's not what your item's unlocalized name actually *is.*

Comment: I eventually figured it out, but this was part of the issue, thank you very much. I don't have 15 rep yet so I can't upvote your answer unfortunately.